# using sing/pl. after 'their'

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> Most of the popular tele-serials are not only illogical in **their storyline(s)** but also crude in **their presentation(s).**"

Please clarify whether it is okay to use 'storyline' and 'presentation' here though they refer to multiple storylines, or only a plural can follow 'their'.

Answer (score 1):

"Most teleserials" is plural, so you are talking about multiple story lines and multiple presentations.  I don't see how this sentence can be singular.

This confusion is easily avoided, and the sentence made more concise, with a simple rewrite:

> Most teleserials **have** illogical storylines and crude presentations.